Identify 6 pin IC, Marcking CUCTC
I am trying to identify the following IC which has marking code CUCTC or CVCTC.


It is likely Silergy SY8009BABC, a 1.5MHz DC-DC step down converter.
From the datasheet, we have the following pin-out and marking numbers given. The SY8009BABC uses marking code CUxyz where the xyz is a date code.

Matching up the middle pin-out to your image, it appears to match your circuit. The LX pin (3) goes to an inductor, the FB pin (6) appears to go to a resistor divider on the other side of the inductor, GND (2) goes to a large plane, NC (5) appears unconnected, and IN (4) goes to what appears to be a power trace. All these match up with the typically application circuit.
The style of the IC marking also matches photographs of that part:

Image Source
